# Theos Hooking an AppDelegate I make some errors

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia, tweak

That's my code... I have some errors... Can you help me?

```
@interface PdfViewerAppDelegate : UIViewController
@property(assign) BOOL myVariable;
 -(void)setup;

@end



%hook PdfViewerAppDelegate

-(void)setup{

    %orig;

    myVariable=1;
}

%end
```

That's the error

```
Compiling Tweak.xm...
Tweak.xm: In function ‘void _logos_method$_ungrouped$PdfViewerAppDelegate$setup(PdfViewerAppDelegate*, objc_selector*)’:
Tweak.xm:15: error: ‘myVariable’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [GG.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

declare "myVariable" as a global variable

Comment: how can I do that using Logos language?

Comment: self.myVariable=1;
or static BOOL myVariable; before @interface PdfViewerAppDelegate : UIViewController

Comment: ok! but now I get this error... Tweak.xm:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘.’ token

Comment: ok I resolved the error using BOOL myVariable; before @interface... Now I get this only error... ld: library not found for -lsubstrate what does it means? What is missed?

Comment: this mean you link libsubstrate.dylib in your makefile, but the linker can not found this dylib in your path.

Comment: search libsubstrate.dylib in Finder or download from net ,and copy it to /opt/theos/bin/lib